# What is the proper way to solve inequalities in WL?

Tags: inequalities

I often have to transform inputs of trigonometric functions which involve finding the new domain. The inequalities themselves are trivial to solve but they get tedious.

```
Reduce[{0<=x<=360°,xT==2x-4°},xT]
```

> 0 <= x <= 360 ° && xT == -4 ° + 2 x

But I want

> ... && -4 ° <= xT <= 716 °

Why can't `Reduce` just give me the transformed inequality? What do I do to find the bounds on the new variable in WL? I tried adding the option `Backsubstitution->True` to no success.

Comment: `Reduce[{0 <= x <= 360 °, 
  xT == 2 x - 4 °}, {xT}, {x}, Reals]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you it works. What kind of syntax is this? I didn't know `Reduce` has more than 3 argument form. Is this even documented? Can you explain what it means when you give variables in two separate lists?

Comment: @user13892  cvgmt's syntax is saying to solve those equations for xT while eliminating x, over the Reals domain. What's being used is an undocumented, but very useful, extension of `Reduce`'s syntax:  `Reduce[{eqns}, {vars}, {elims}, Domain]`, which means "For the equation(s) {eqns}, solve for the variable(s) {vars}, while eliminating the variable(s) {elims}, under the domain Domain".  The undocumented extension is {elims}.

Comment: Worth thinking about the order of the variables: `Reduce[{0 <= x <= 360 \[Degree], xT == 2 x - 4 \[Degree]}, {xT, x}, Reals]` -- The given input is already reduce (in one way), and `Reduce` does not always solve a system in the "other way" as we might imagine it.